# useEffect not getting called in my component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
const CompanyDetailsForm = ({
  formfields,
  handleInputChange,
  modalChecker,
  handleModalClick,
  modal,
  isCompanyOpen,
  handleCompanyClick,
  isSubmitting,
  handleFocusOnError,
}: Props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('trying to do');
    if (isCompanyOpen) {
      handleFocusOnError();
      console.log('trying to render');
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {modalChecker.modal.error && modal && (
        <ModalPopup
          warningMessage={WARNING_CONFIRM_PERSON}
          onClick={handleModalClick}
          success={false}
        />
      )}

      <ToggleDiv
        toggleDivStyle={inputContainerLabel}
        labelStyle={labelStyle}
        label={COMPANY_DETAILS}
        onClick={handleCompanyClick}
        isCollapsed={isCompanyOpen}
      />
      <div style={isCompanyOpen ? hideDisplay : inputDiv}>
        <div style={inputFieldContainer}>
          <div style={firstInputColumn}>
            <div style={inputContainer}>
              <Nunito20 style={inputLabel}>{COMPANY_FORM_INPUT_NAME}</Nunito20>
              <InputValidation
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={formfields.name.value}
                handleInputChange={event =>
                  handleInputChange('name', event.target.value)
                }
                hasError={formfields.name.hasError}
                validationMessage={ERROR_REQUIRED}
              />
            </div>
```

Why can this happen and how do I make sure useEffect gets called?
For debugging i put console.log messages and none is getting triggered.
What possible syntax error might I have missed?

Comment: Assuming your project is building properly, Try adding `isCompanyOpen` to the dependency array of the `useEffect` as that will make it re-run every time the `isCompanyOpen` prop changes. You might also have to add `handleFocusOnError` as well or store it in a ref depending on how referentially stable it is.

Comment: I would definitely add `handleFocusOnError` too as you can't rely on it always being stable even if it is for now.

Comment: it should actually

Comment: May I please ask you, if you found a solution? I have the same problem and I am trying to solve it for at least 3 hours without any success :) Thank you